# Java queues and thread safety

Tags: java, thread-safety, queue

im looking for a queue which doesnt allow duplicate elements (older duplicate element is always removed and at the end of the queue is new a new element added). and is thread-safe. one thread is adding elements to queue and second one is reading and removing elements.
Is anything useful in standart java libs, or in guava/apache?

Comment: You are talking about JMS queue ?

Comment: "doesnt allow duplicate elements" <-- according to what criteria? equals and hashCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, for instance, Guava's `Forwarding{,Blocking}{Queue,Deque}`.

What you would then do is also have a `HashSet` as part of your implementation from which you would try and `.add()` new elements; if `.add()` returns false, don't add to the delegate.

And, of course, don't forget to `.remove()` from the set either when you remove elements from the queue!

(this supposes that by "duplicate" here you mean "are .equals()"; if on the other hand you use a `PriorityQueue` you would want to use a `TreeSet` instead)